# Having trouble with LargeTitle and a segmented control with a table view

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, nslayoutconstraint

**Sample project can be found at https://github.com/SRowley90/LargeTitleIssueTestiOS**

I am trying to position a segmented control below the Large title in an iOS app. I have a UIToolbar which contains the segmented control inside.

When scrolling up the `title` and `toolbar` behave as expected.

When scrolling down the navigation bar is correct, but it doesn't push the UITabBar or the UITableView down, meaning the title goes above the segmented control as can be seen in the images below.

I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the constraints I have set, but I can't figure out what.

- The TabBar is fixed to the top, left and right.
- The TableView is fixed to the bottom, left and right.
- The tableView is fixed vertically to the TabBar

I have the position UITabBarDelegate method set:

```
func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
    return .topAttached
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload you sample project somewhere to investigate the issue?

Comment: Added a link to GitHub with an example of the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote an answer to your issue. Check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the delegation of the `tableView` somewhere:
`tableView.delegate = self`

Override the `scrollViewDidScroll` and update `toolbar` position appearance (since the real position should not change according to have that nice bounce effect.

```swift
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        var verticalOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y + defaultNavigationBarHeight

        if scrollView.refreshControl?.isRefreshing ?? false {
            verticalOffset += 60 // After is refreshing changes its value the toolbar goes 60 points down
            print(toolbar.frame.origin.y)
        }

        if verticalOffset >= 0 {
            toolbar.transform = .identity
        } else {
            toolbar.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -verticalOffset)
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the following check before applying transformation to make it more reliable and natural to default iOS style:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    guard let navigationController = navigationController else { return }
    guard navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles else { return }
    guard navigationController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode != .never else { return }
}
```

Comment: It works and I did try something like this already, I would have thought that the system would handle pushing the view down though. I'll accept the answer though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `UIScrollViewDelegate` didn't work well with CollectionView and toolbar for me. So, I did:

```swift
final class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
private var observesBag: [NSKeyValueObservation] = []
private let toolbar = UIToolbar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
        let navigationBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0
        let defaultNavigationBarHeight = statusBarHeight + navigationBarHeight

        let observation = navigationController!
            .navigationBar
            .observe(\.center, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new) { [weak self] navBar, _ in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                let newNavigatonBarHeight = navBar.frame.height + statusBarHeight
                let yTranslantion = newNavigatonBarHeight - defaultNavigationBarHeight
                if yTranslantion > 0 {
                    self.toolbar.transform = CGAffineTransform(
                        translationX: 0,
                        y: yTranslantion
                    )
                } else {
                    self.toolbar.transform = .identity
                }

        }
        observesBag.append(observation)
    }
}
```

Observe the "center" of the `navigationBar` for changes and then translate the `toolbar` in the y-axis.

Even though it worked fine when I tried to use this solution with `UIRefreshControl` and Large Titles it didn't work well. 
I set up the refresh control like:

```
   private func setupRefreshControl() {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        self.webView.scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    }
```

the height of the `UINavigationBar` is changed after the complete refresh triggers.